# Unable to install pgAdmin on MacOS Big Sur; possible verification problem

Tags: install, big-sur, verify

So, I potentially have a stupid yet hopefully quick issue; I am attempting to install the latest version of pgAdmin onto my Macbook Pro with the M1 chip running Big Sur. When I attempt to open the installation package nothing happens and it refuses to open. I *believe* it may be a verification issue, but not 100% certain.

Does anyone know how to (preferably simply) resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

that program needs to install software in non standard locations. I don't have the equipment you have but am confident this is a Big Sur issue.
Go TO System Preferences:Security and Privacy:Full Disk Access (on the sidebar)
You will likely need to authenticate then add the pgAdmin installer.
Untested and best guess answer...